# On which Stack Exchange sites are the set of people answering most similar to the set of people asking?

Tags: discussion, community

Does Stack Exchange collect, or can calculate, any metrics which would give an indication of which site an individual user is likely to both ask and answer questions?

I ask because in the brief time I've been perusing the various sites, it seems with a few notable exceptions (e.g. Puzzling) that there isn't much overlap between the askers and the answerers.

Comment: All the data is availble for you if you can construct your own query: https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might see this on beta or newer sites, since they usually have less organic traffic and fewer total questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've constructed a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/980197/sites-where-the-top-askers-are-similar-to-the-top-answerers?Limit=100) which compares the top X askers (by # of questions asked) to the top X answerers (by # of answers posted). Running it with X = 100 declares [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) as the winner with a 55% overlap, followed by three sites with 52%.

[image]

The query excludes child meta sites; those generally have a much larger overlap than main sites, as can be seen in [a previous revision](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/980197/1214436/sites-where-the-top-askers-are-similar-to-the-top-answerers) of the query.

The outcome will certainly depend on the value of X; if you [increase it to 1000](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/980197/sites-where-the-top-askers-are-similar-to-the-top-answerers?Limit=1000), Meta Stack Exchange leads the board with 59%.

Comment: That's intriguing especially as X tends to large numbers, if anything it tells me I need to formulate the question more carefully.  Thank you for taking the time to construct the query.

Comment: Yeah, if X is bigger than the actual # of users, you're guaranteed to hit 100%. This method was the best I could think of (and model in SEDE) on Sunday evening; it's just one possible way to measure it.

Comment: It would probably be best to make X site specific (eg. 2% of total unique askers on that site)